# Is there any adjective for describing a person who prefers his/her friends to his/her family?

Tags: idiom-requests, compound-adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective /idiom /expression /phrase with a negative connotation, for describing someone who spends their time mostly with their friends, and prefer their friends to their own family, even though they are married.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only phrase that comes to mind is a negative one, "He's not a family man."

> family man noun [C] uk    us
>
> ```
>      a man who has a ​wife and ​children, or who ​enjoys ​spending a lot of ​time with them
> ```
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/family-man)

It's a very well-known idiom so I think it's suitable to your context.

Comment: Waylon might call him a "good-timin' man".  But this type has wicked ways too, so it wouldn't necessary apply.    Estranged or alienated is too strong since the description is “prefer”.  I think Chasly hits it right on the head.

Answer (score 1):

**He/She is not** **family-oriented**.

A family oriented man/woman is devoted to his/her family and prefers to be with them.

> - Being family oriented can carry several meanings, depending on the context in which it is being used -- but at its core, being family oriented is appreciating your family, your relationship and the relationship that your partner shares with his or her family. Being family oriented is a state of mind that guides your actions with friends, family and in relationships. Individuals who consider themselves family oriented may come from a strong religious background, may have a tightly knit family, or may long to start a family with the right person. (from [cs.com](http://classroom.synonym.com/family-oriented-means-11672.html))

Comment: +1, Thanks @Centaurus, appropriate phrase. Can I say "someone is friend-oriented"?

Comment: @J008 I never hear it.  "friendmaker" fits better. "an interesting person whose biggest talent is to make friends/contacts in all sorts of circles and whatever the circumstances are."